# Why can't I import pictures from my moto g6 (Android 9) into Shotwell on Debian Bullseye?

Tags: troubleshooting, android, import

I used to import my  phone pictures into Shotwell on a Debian computer by doing something like

1. Plug the phone into a USB connector on my laptop.
2. Set the phone's USB Preferences so that "USE USB for File Transfer" is selected.
3. Open Shotwell, click on the G6 icon, and import all the new pictures.
4. Set the USE USB to No data transfer.

When I try today, I find that Shotwell hangs while saying "Connecting to computer, please wait" or "The camera is locked by another application," even if I've just rebooted the camera and opened no apps.

It is likely that I last did this on Debian OldOldStable; I am now on Debian Stable. I can't think of a likely reason that would make a difference.

I do see the option to set USB controlled by to Connected device, but it tries and then reports it "Couldn't switch."

I have re-read the pertinent device user manual section and the instructions at https://support.google.com/android/answer/9064445?hl=en and at https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-217592/ and at https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/import-photos-on-linux-with-shotwell/ .  I think that's what I'm doing.

Any ideas?

Edit: after initially posting this, I tried importing pictures from another camera's SD card, just to make sure Shotwell could do that. It worked just as I expected from past experience.

Bill

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about photography, it is a technical support issue that would probably be better addressed by the software developer's support channels, or perhaps http://superuser.com/ or https://android.stackexchange.com/